# Как узнать какая позиция выбранного item в AutocompleteTextView?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Есть `AutocompleteTextView,` как узнать, какую позицию из массива выбрал пользователь? Когда использую `arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()` в `onItemClick()`, то показывается номер позиции из выпадающего списка, а не номер позиции этого элемента в массиве.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] language ={"C 5351","C++ 5478","Java 2367",".net 7890"," iphone 9654","android  5432","asp.net 9765","php 3290"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,language);
        final AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        actv.setThreshold(1);
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);
        actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "you chose item "+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)+"position:"+
                        arg0.getSelectedItemPosition(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить позицию выбранного элемента, можно массив преобразовать в список (`List`), и у него спросить, на какой позиции находится элемент

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(language).indexOf(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2))
```

Comment: ааа, ок, спасибо!

Comment: Только что проверила еще раз arg2 выдает позицию выпадающих позиций, а не позицию в массиве.

Comment: @Lucky_girl, а почему они должны быть разные? И про какой массив вообще идет речь?

Comment: про массив в котором лежат все значения, в данном случае массив language

Comment: @Lucky_girl, в вашем случае это одно и то же. Т. к. вы используете массив `language`, как source для адаптера, то и номер выбранного элемента из списка будет совпадать с номером этого элемента в массиве

Comment: нет, они не совпадают, например я набираю букву " a", я выбираю  "android" и если я вывожу  arg2  в лог,  то получаю 0.

Comment: @Lucky_girl, пардон, я почему-то перепутал AutoCompleteTextVIew с обычным Spinner. Сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: Работает, спасибо!